# RewriteCond appending querystring

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using .htaccess file to redirect my archived old aspx urls to my new php site. Now the requirement is as follows:
example.com/showad.aspx?adid=1234 should be example.com/ad/getad/1234
I googled the matter and got the following htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^adid=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^showad\.aspx$ /ad/getad/%1
```

The rule works except that the resulting url is example.com/ad/getad/1234?adid=1234
I searched again and learned that to remove the (adid=1234) at the end of the output url you should place a question mark ? at the end of the substitution parameter, so that the rule should be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^adid=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^showad\.aspx$ /ad/getad/%1?
```

But it doesn't work!
The resulting url is STILL having the original query string appended to it. I am using this site to test my htaccess rules: htaccess.madewithlove.be
Any clues why is this happening?

Comment: I don't see how this rule would do a redirect without the `[R]` flag? The second code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your rule to

```
RewriteRule ^showad\.aspx$ /ad/getad/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule`s only deal with the part after the slash - the slash after the domain should neither be matched nor rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is fine - I just tested it in my own .htaccess. It's the htaccess tester website that's wrong :)

Comment: Did you try actually running this on your server?